# Transferring domains when registered owner's email address is incorrect

Tags: domain, domain-name, domain-registrar

Years ago I registered some domains using a now expired university email address. The other contact details for the registered owner (postal address and phone number) are still correct. In order to change/update the email address, the registrar wants to charge £20 a domain.

I would like to transfer the domains away from the current registrar. I can unlock the domains and generate an auth code. However, I cannot authorise the transfer by email as any emails sent to the registered owner's address will bounce. This seems to rule out most registrars I have tried.

Are there any ways to transfer these domains without paying the £20 fee to update the registered owner's details?

Comment: What sort of half-baked university doesn't give out lifetime email accounts this day in age?

Comment: £20 isn't a huge amount as a one-off cost to retain domains that can represent you for years to come. How much does your annual registration and hosting bill come to? Personally I'd just pay it to get rid of the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually calling your registrar's phone support? It is situations like this that it exists for.

Comment: They'll probably just repeat it will cost the 20 pounds...?

Comment: @Arjan: Never assume that, alot of times Agents will have more leeway than an automated systems, you could also try escalating to a manager. It's amazing what you can do by talking to a real person (assuming it's not an IVR :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens all the time. As others have stated, call the registrar, pay the fee (yes I know, it's highway robbery), transfer the domains, and get on to more important tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the admins at the uni, explain your problem, and ask them to create a temporary email address to match the one you used for registering the domains so that you can at least update your details at the registrar. They'll probably so no initially but then you could offer them at least part of what it would cost you otherwise. I don't know about the UK but here in Oz such a thing usually costs a slab (carton) of beer. ;)